# iOS Offer Code show a message error "this offer already expired"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to use iOS Offer Codes in my app. I've implemented `presentCodeRedemptionSheet()` method to show redemption view.
In the App Store Connect i've setted and created 500 offer codes. After downloaded i tried to use them in my app, but for every code i use, it shows a message error: "this offer already expired". I'm sure that the codes are valid.

Comment: I got the same thing, then tried the next day and they started working. I'm in the same position again and am wondering if there is a set time before the promo codes actually become active.

Comment: The only thing that i noticed is that the app must be approved and live on the app store, and then you can use offer codes properly

Comment: What if app is under development? How can we test it?

Answer (score 1):

After creating offer codes, wait 2 hours and more. Then they start working.